# Listview isvisible property is not working from the code behind?

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to show the selected image or file on my UI on a listview. Initially the listview's `IsVisible` I set to false and after picking item, I set the `IsVisible` property to true. My problem is after picking item the listview is not visible on the UI.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MediaPickerDemo.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <ListView 
                x:Name="attachment_listview"
                IsVisible="false"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                SelectionMode="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout
                                Margin="5,10"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                Orientation="Vertical">

                                <Image 
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    x:Name="attachmentPicture"
                                    Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                                    <Image.WidthRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>100</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>150</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>100</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.WidthRequest>
                                    <Image.HeightRequest>
                                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                            <OnIdiom.Phone>100</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                            <OnIdiom.Tablet>150</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                            <OnIdiom.Desktop>100</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                        </OnIdiom>
                                    </Image.HeightRequest>
                                </Image>

                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label 
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        x:Name="attachmentname_label"
                                        Text="{Binding attachemntName}"
                                        TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                        <Label.FontSize>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                <OnIdiom.Phone>13</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>20</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>13</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                            </OnIdiom>
                                        </Label.FontSize>
                                    </Label>

                                    <Button 
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                        x:Name="AttachmentRemove_Stack"
                                        Text="Remove"
                                        Style="{StaticResource RemoveButtonStyle}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.HeightRequest>
                    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>220</OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>330</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                        <OnIdiom.Desktop>220</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                    </OnIdiom>
                </ListView.HeightRequest>
            </ListView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FileResult> choosedFiles;
    public ObservableCollection<MultipleAttachments> attachmentList;
    FileResult photo;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        attachmentList = new ObservableCollection<MultipleAttachments>();
    }

    private async void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string action = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, "Photo", "File");
        if (action == "Photo")
        {
            string action1 = await DisplayActionSheet(null, "Cancel", null, "Take photo", "Upload from gallery");
            if (action1 == "Take photo")
            {
                CameraClick();
            }
            else if (action1 == "Upload from gallery")
            {
                GalleryClick();
            }
        }
        else if (action == "File")
        {
            try
            {
                choosedFiles = await FilePicker.Default.PickMultipleAsync();
                foreach (var item in choosedFiles.ToList())
                {
                    attachmentList.Add(new MultipleAttachments()
                    {
                        attachemntName = item.FileName,
                        ImageSource = "ic_doc_xx.png".ToString(),
                        TextColor = Colors.Black,
                        type = "file",
                        path = item.FullPath
                    });
                    attachment_listview.IsVisible = true;
                    attachment_listview.ItemsSource = attachmentList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("exception:>>" + ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void CameraClick()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                if (photo != null)
                {
                    var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
                    using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
                    using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                        await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

                    attachmentList.Add(new MultipleAttachments()
                    {
                        attachemntName = Path.GetFileName(photo.FullPath),
                        ImageSource = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName),
                        TextColor = Colors.Black,
                        type = "image",
                        path = photo.FullPath
                    });
                    attachment_listview.IsVisible = true;
                    attachment_listview.ItemsSource = attachmentList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception:>" + ex);
        }
    }

    async void GalleryClick()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
                if (photo != null)
                {
                    var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
                    using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
                    using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                        await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

                    attachmentList.Add(new MultipleAttachments()
                    {
                        attachemntName = Path.GetFileName(photo.FullPath),
                        ImageSource = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName),
                        TextColor = Colors.Black,
                        type = "image",
                        path = photo.FullPath
                    });
                    attachment_listview.IsVisible = true;
                    attachment_listview.ItemsSource = attachmentList;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("gallery Exception:>" + ex);
        }
    }
}

public class MultipleAttachments : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string attachemntName { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }

    private ImageSource imageSource;
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                imageSource = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return imageSource;
        }
    }

    private Color textColor;
    public Color TextColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                textColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return textColor;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

If I remove the `IsVisible="false"` from xaml file the items are showing on the UI, but I need the listview in hide state initially.

**Update**

**On my Viewmodel**

```
private bool mediaVisibility = false;
public bool MediaVisibility
{
    get
    {
        return mediaVisibility;
    }
    set
    {
        mediaVisibility = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MediaVisibility));
    }
}
```

**On MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
//created viewmodel variable
MediaViewModel mvm;
......
.....
//BindingContext added
mvm = new MediaViewModel();
BindingContext = mvm;

//inside camera, gallery and filepicker
mvm.MediaVisibility = true;
```

**In XAMl**

```xml
<ListView 
    x:Name="attachment_listview"
    Margin="0,0,10,10"
    IsVisible="{Binding MediaVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    ....
```

@Mert Altiparmak After adding data binding like above the listview is not visible on the UI and I didn't get what service you are mentioning in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by replacing the `Listview` with a `CollectionView`.

After picking a picture from galery or camera and picking a file from device, the `CollectionView` is visible on the UI with the selected items.

But the items are not visible with `Listview`.

**Update**

This is probably [[regression/8.0.0-preview.5.8529] [Android] ListView doesn't get rendered #15826](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15826), which is fixed in the .Net 8RC.

Answer (score 0):

You should use viewmodel. Example:

```
private bool personelKoduGorunurluk;
public bool PersonelKoduGorunurluk
    {
        get => personelKoduGorunurluk; set
        {
            personelKoduGorunurluk = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Service Call :

```
if (serviceCall[0].PERSONEL_VSB == true)
        {

            PersonelKoduGorunurluk = true;
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
        else if (serviceCall[0].PERSONEL_VSB == false)
        {

            PersonelKoduGorunurluk = false;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
```

Xaml :

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppName.ViewModels"
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:DepoAktarımPageViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Property:

```
IsVisible="{Binding PersonelKoduGorunurluk}"
```

I use it like that. When user open that page information taken from service and set properties. Then page shown labels, buttons etc.
If you want to set IsVisible property with button click you should use command. You can just set your property false and true.

Comment: What is the logic behind Service Call?

Comment: I already tried the data binding, but not worked. My intension is to show the listview when the first item is added.

Comment: @Sreejith I got parameters from service. I set visibility properties from service information.

Comment: what service you are talking about?

Comment: I use my service, I take information from api and set visibilities. Service is irrelevant your question.

Comment: I have updated the question with the data binding logic I tried, could you please check?

Comment: If I understand you correctly; you want to hide listview when user pick something in this listview, right ?

Comment: You understood the problem wrong. I need to show the listview when I choose a picture from gallery or camera and when i choose the file. Not hiding the listview.

Comment: I have created a sample and uploaded here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HfApwVwrIwEoGWruPRkZND2XViyjlEKW/view
My problem is lisview is not visible on the UI with IsVisible property.
After picking an image or file I am showing it on the UI using listview.
If I remove IsVisible="false" from xaml, the items are visible on the UI. But I need the listview in hide initially.
I have also tried data binding and but not succeeded, and I have added the entire details on the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide listview when you tap on it you can use code like this :

**Xaml:**

```
 <ListView x:Name="denemeListView" ItemTapped="denemeListView_ItemTapped" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="Deneme" FontSize="24" TextColor="Red"></Label>
                        
                        
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public SaveDeneme()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        filllist();
    }

private void denemeListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        denemeListView.IsVisible = false;

    }



void filllist()
    {

        strings.Add("Mert");
        

        denemeListView.ItemsSource = strings;
    }
```

You can use this "logic" with mvvm structure also.
Use Xamarin Community Toolkit to make EventToCommand and then write a new function, check null of this *ItemTappedEventArgs e* if its not null change parameter of listview visibility.